# Keycloak for unified login

Tags: keycloak, identity-management

My company is building a few related applications and we recently began looking into using Keycloak for IAM. We are finishing up our MVPs, but one feature we always planned to integrate is a unified login across these related applications (i.e. user can use the same credentials to login to each application). Apart from this, we also have the following requirements:

1. All new users create an organization upon registering and become the sole user of that organization.
2. A user can be invited to one or more organizations.
3. A user can have the same or completely different role/permissions across each organization they join.
4. The user's array of organizations can be different across each application.

We know we can use Keycloak for the multi-org functionality, but is it also possible to achieve our other requirements using Keycloak? If yes, how could we achieve this?

We've looked into creating a single realm with multiple organizations and using the PhaseTwo library but we can't figure out if this would support unified login.